# Filling a column with the amount of duplicated values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, counting, np

I have a df like this:

| month | outcome | mom.ret |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/20 | winner | 0.2 |
| 10/20 | winner | 0.9 |
| 11/20 | winner | 0.6 |
| 11/20 | winner | 0.2 |
| 11/20 | winner | 0.9 |
| 10/20 | loser | 0.6 |
| 10/20 | loser | 0.2 |
| 10/20 | loser | 0.9 |
| 11/20 | loser | 0.6 |

I would like to add another column, which has 1 / by the counts of times the value "winner" or "loser" appears per each month on the column outcome. The expected output for the example df is:

| month | outcome | mom.ret | q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/20 | winner | 0.2 | 1/2 |
| 10/20 | winner | 0.9 | 1/2 |
| 11/20 | winner | 0.6 | 1/3 |
| 11/20 | winner | 0.2 | 1/3 |
| 11/20 | winner | 0.9 | 1/3 |
| 10/20 | loser | 0.6 | 1/3 |
| 10/20 | loser | 0.2 | 1/3 |
| 10/20 | loser | 0.9 | 1/3 |
| 11/20 | loser | 0.6 | 1/1 |

I thought of using the function count to count how many times the values are repeated, but then I need to specify that the "count" should be done per each date. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the first df. Now it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to achieve what you want, assuming your original DataFrame is called `df`:

```
counts = df.groupby(['month', 'outcome'], as_index=False).count()
counts = counts.rename(columns={'mom.ret': 'q'})
# Use this line if you want the float value of the division 0.5
# counts['q'] = 1/counts['q']
# Use this line if you want the string '1/2'
counts['q'] = counts['q'].apply(lambda x: f'1/{x}')
result = pd.merge(df, counts)
```

The result looks like this:

```
month   outcome mom.ret q
0   10/20   winner  0.2 1/2
1   10/20   winner  0.9 1/2
2   11/20   winner  0.6 1/3
3   11/20   winner  0.2 1/3
4   11/20   winner  0.9 1/3
5   10/20   loser   0.6 1/2
6   10/20   loser   0.2 1/2
7   11/20   loser   0.9 1/2
8   11/20   loser   0.6 1/2
```

Comment: I think it should be counts['outcome'].apply(...

Comment: This has generated an error, but it worked after I replaced the last line of code for: 
  ` result = pd.merge(df, counts[['month', 'q']], on='month') `

Answer (score 1):

Use `df['q'] = 1/df.groupby(['month', 'outcome']).transform('count')`.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

@timgeb's required a groupby of just the month for me. To output a fraction instead of a decimal, I used the handy [humanize library](https://pypi.org/project/humanize/).

```py
import humanize      # pip install humanize # if needed

df['q'] = 1 / df.groupby(['month', 'outcome'])['month'].transform('count')
df['q'] = df['q'].apply(lambda x : humanize.fractional(x))
```

Note that you can't just use `.count()` with the groupby - you need the transform method to return a Series of the same length as the original DataFrame.

Using Python 3.9.7, pandas 1.4.1

Code to make the original df (I left out the *mom.ret* column that wasn't germane).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "month": [
            "10/20",
            "10/20",
            "11/20",
            "11/20",
            "11/20",
            "10/20",
            "10/20",
            "10/20",
            "11/20",
        ],
        "outcome": [
            "winner",
            "winner",
            "winner",
            "winner",
            "winner",
            "loser",
            "loser",
            "loser",
            "loser",
        ],
    }
)
```

Comment: I have executed your version of the code. However, the final numbers are not right. I think it is because we should group by "month" and "outcome", since we have for the same month, winners and losers. I have added the argument "outcome" inside groupby to account for that, but then my code returns "1/winners" instead of numbers in the end.

Comment: My bad. Updated the brief solution to do what you asked.